# How can I create a new element with html special character content in MooTools?

Tags: mootools

I'm trying to convert about 200 lines of my jQuery code into MooTools to avoid including two libraries on an existing site. I'm having a problem with just one line:

```
new Element('span', {text: ' &raquo; '}).inject(elem);
```

Once I inject the span, the text becomes:

```
&amp;raquo;"
```

How can I prevent MooTools from escaping the ampersand? Here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nHhSY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use

```
new Element('span', {html: ' &raquo; '}).inject(elem);
```